# How to slow down the sorting in a sorting visualizer? for better clarity?

Tags: python, sorting, pysimplegui

I am making a sorting algorithm visualizer, I have just managed to complete the bubble sort. So the problem is that the graph sorts instantly.

**Minimal Code:**

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg 
from random import randint 
from time import sleep
sg.theme('Dark')


hlayout1 = #LAYOUT FOR THE WINDOW

window = sg.Window('Sort Visualizer',hlayout1)


while True:
    event,value = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == '--[RANDOM]--':
        #Generates a random array to the Graph. 
    if event=='--[SORT]--':     
        n = len(array) 
        for i in range(n): 
            swapped = False
            for j in range(0, n-1):  
                if array[j] > array[j+1] : 
                    array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
                    
                    #Need to do something here.... Lets refer this as A
                    
                    swapped = True
            # IF no two elements were swapped 
            # by inner loop, then break 
            if swapped == False: 
                break
        canvas.erase()                           #These three lines refresh the 
        for idx,i in enumerate(array):           #graph, Lets refer this as 
            canvas.draw_line((idx+5,0),(idx+5,i))#Refresher
window.close()
```

**What I have Tried**-

1. `time.sleep()` and move the refresher lines into the Block A
2. PySimpleGui.Graph's method - `Graph.move_figure` in A
3. And using a tkinter canvas with Pysimplegui.

But in all of these I see that array lags for 3-4 minutes and snaps instantly to the sorted position. *I don't have problem sorting the lines just making it slightly more interactive*

Maybe the problem lies in my old laptop not being able to render it properly. Since I move the Refresher to to A its a loop inside a loop inside a loop. And if its gonna snap to the sorted positions then its better to use `array.sort()`? It will use less iterations and will be more efficient. A online tutorial on geeks for geeks uses Pygame and its time.delay() function. Should I drop Pysimplegui and use Pygame to make the same thing?

Comment: I can post full code if required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GUI event loop, GUI refresh only at when `window.read()`.
Any change on GUI will not be updated during one event loop, and after all steps of your sorting completed, you can only find the last state of GUI.

If you want each step shown when something changed in GUI, what you need is to add one statement after you change GUI, like

```py
graph = window['-GRAPH-']
graph.move_figure(figure, x_direction, y_direction)
window.refresh()
```

Then it will show you each step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me alot. Now I have a new problem, I need to manually click sort all the time. I can't post a video here but it stops after 1 sorting iteration.you click again and and again to sort it all

Comment: So how to make it automatically click sort in a loop

Comment: Not sure what you mean for "automatically click sort in a loop".

Comment: You see the window.refresh() ends the event. it sends the largest line to the end and stops. I click sort button again I send second largest number to back and so on and so forth.

Comment: if you want to run it  https://paste.pythondiscord.com/inupememuq.php

Comment: You can use option `timeout=100` of `window.read`, then it will loop again after 100ms if no other event generated. Of course, you need to check when to sorting, loop directly, or sorting done, ....

Answer (score 0):

You must update the image after every swap. In this example I print the new array after every swap. After or before you update the image you can add a time delay, like the comment after the print statement.

```
def bubbleSort(array):
    n = len(array)
    for i in range(n):
        swapped = False
        for j in range(n-i-1):
            if array[j] > array[j + 1]:
                array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]
                swapped = True
                print(array) #Update Image, Graph, Visual ..etc Redraw after every swap
                #time.sleep() this is where you would insert a delay for visual effect
        if not swapped:
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I mentioned I tried that to no avail